# Python: how can I get the mode from a month column that i extracted from a datetime column?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new at this! Doing my first Python project. :)
My tasks are:

1. convert df['Start Time'] from string to datetime
2. create a month column from df['Start Time']
3. get the mode of that month.

I used a few different ways to do all 3 of the steps, but trying to get the mode always returns **TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str**. This happens even if I try converting the "tuple" into a list or NumPy array.

Ways I tried to extract month from Start Time:

```
df['extracted_month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Start Time']).month
df['extracted_month'] = np.asarray(df['extracted_month'])
df['extracted_month'] = df['Start Time'].dt.month
```

Ways I've tried to get the mode:

```
print(df['extracted_month'].mode())
print(df['extracted_month'].mode()[0])
print(stat.mode(df['extracted_month']))
```

Trying to get the index with **df.columns.get_loc("extracted_month")** then replacing it in the mode code gives me the SAME error (**TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str**).

I think I should convert df['extracted_month'] into a different... something. What is it?

Note: My extracted_month column is a STRING, but you should still be able to get the mode from a string variable! I'm not changing it, that would be giving up.

Edit: using the following code still results in the same error

```
extracted_month = pd.Index(df['extracted_month'])
print(extracted_month.value_counts())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is likely caused by the way you are creating your dataframe.
If the dataframe is created in another function, and that function returns other things along with the dataframe, but you assign it to the variable df, then df will be a tuple that contains the actual dataframe, and not the dataframe itself.

Comment: True! Fixing the way I assign df in main() resolves the issue:
`df, city_filter, month_filter, day_filter = load_data(city_filter, month_filter, day_filter)`